# Why am I getting this error: TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getSpreadsheetById is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is surely a newbie question but I am breaking my head over it. I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong!
I have the following script which is incomplete and definitely incorrect. But my issue is that when I run it, I get the following error:

> TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getSpreadsheetById is not a function

This is the script:

```
function matchRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var ts = SpreadsheetApp.getSpreadsheetById('1Sq5prZI4a_UwesPTUQLnmXvtpJClyMcMlHM-m3JrE6g').getSheetByName('Quiz advertiser');
  var countryIndex = ('Spain', 'Germany', 'France');
  var getLastRowByMatch = matchRow();
   if (ss.countryIndex = 'Spain');
   getss.LastRowByMatch;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `Quiz advertiser` sheet is in the same spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpreadsheetApp.getSpreadsheetById` doesn't exist. Instead of

```
var ts = SpreadsheetApp.getSpreadsheetById('1Sq5prZI4a_UwesPTUQLnmXvtpJClyMcMlHM-m3JrE6g').getSheetByName('Quiz advertiser');
```

use

```
var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Sq5prZI4a_UwesPTUQLnmXvtpJClyMcMlHM-m3JrE6g').getSheetByName('Quiz advertiser');
```

By the way, the lines after the referred one doesn't make any sense. It looks that you have to spend some time reviewing https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app